# Can $\int^{b}_{a} \Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right) \phi(x) dx$ be obtained in closed-form

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Suppose that $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are CDF and PDF of a standard Normal random variable.

Is it possible to compute:

$$\int^{b}_{a} \Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}  \right)  \phi(x) dx$$

(where a and b are any real numbers) in closed form? What if we set $a=0$?

---

I know that if $b=\infty$ and $a=-\infty$ then one can show that

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}  \right)  \phi(x) dx = \Phi\left(\frac{-\mu}{\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\right)$$

[See the link: computations of the above integral](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw?rq=1)

But what if $a>-\infty$ and $b<\infty$?

---

The way one computes the above integral when $b=\infty$ and $a=-\infty$ is by considering
$$ I(\mu)= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}  \right)  \phi(x) dx $$

Then computing $$I_{\mu}=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\left[ \Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}  \right)  \phi(x)  \right]dx$$

which can be easily computed, and which gives a pdf of normal distribution. Then integrating with respect to $\mu$ yields the final result.

However, if I follow the above steps I obtain:
$$ I_{\mu}= \phi\left(\frac{-\mu}{\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\right) 
\left[ \Phi\left( \frac{b-\frac{\mu}{1+\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{1+\sigma^2}}} \right) - \Phi\left( \frac{a-\frac{\mu}{1+\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{1+\sigma^2}}} \right) \right]$$

which I do not know how to integrate with respect to $\mu$ in order to compute $I(\mu)$.

Is there any hope to somehow compute this integral?

Comment: Yes, it can. Hint: your integrand has the form g(x) g'(x) = 1/2 d/dx ( g(x)^2 )

Comment: I can see how this helps in the case when $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. But I don't see how to use this observation in the general case... Would you mind explaining a bit more.

Comment: It does not apply to the general case.

Comment: I see, thanks. I still have a hope this can be computes somehow. One of the comments on stats.stackexchange in the topic linked above states that it can be computed. But I tried for a couple of days now and can't get it...

Comment: I consulted Gradshteyn/Ryshik, tried Fouriertransform and series expansions with respect to $\ sigma$ and $\ mu$ but no avail.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the effort! I appreciate the time you put into thinking about this integral!

Comment: Could you tell us something about a possible application backgound of your problem?

Comment: This integral came in a game theory problem I have been trying to analyze. There are two players and they can take either safe or risky action. Safe action yields 0. An integral of the above integral form is part of the payoff from a risky action.

Comment: More details about the problem: The variable x is unobserved but it is believed to be distributed according to $N(0,1)$. The payoff from risky action to Player 1 is equal to 1 if x>b, is 1 if $x\in[a,b]$ AND Player 2 takes the risky action, and -T, T>0, otherwise. The CDF that appears in the integrand in the problem captures the probability that the other player attacks.

Comment: In the last comment I wrote "other player attacks." It should be "other player takes the risky action." In my particular context, the risky action is attacking a currency peg. Basically, I am working on the 2-player version of paper by Morris and Shin "Unique Equilibrium in a Model of Self-Fulfilling Currency Attacks."